# Python CNN. How to get the hidden fc layer encoding of data?pytho

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm trying to run CNN on my personal data of images. I got reasonable results but my code is very rough.

At the moment I have 2 problems:
1) I'd like to use the last hidden fc layer as encoding of the data and use other classification method over the "new" dataset, how can I do it? 
2) How can I automatically compute the size of the input of the first fc layer? I have 48x64 images and when I change something in the architecture I have to manually change the w3 value in the variables_lenet5 method.

I'm using Tensorflow. This is the core of my sript:

```
def variables_lenet5(filter_size = filter_size_1,
                 filter_size_2=filter_size_2, 
                 filter_depth1 = filter_size_1, 
                 filter_depth2 = filter_size_2,
                 num_hidden1 = hid_1, 
                 num_hidden2 = hid_2,
                 #num_hidden3 = hid_3,
                 image_width = image_width, 
                 image_height = image_height, 
                 image_depth = 3, 
                 num_labels = num_labels):

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([filter_size, filter_size, image_depth, filter_depth1], stddev=0.1))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([filter_depth1]))

w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([filter_size_2, filter_size_2, filter_depth1, filter_depth2], stddev=0.1))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[filter_depth2]))

#w2_a = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden3,num_labels], stddev=0.1))
#b2_a = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_labels]))

w3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([288, num_hidden1], stddev=0.1)) 
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape = [num_hidden1]))

w4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden1, num_hidden2], stddev=0.1))
b4 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape = [num_hidden2]))

w5 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden2, num_labels], stddev=0.1))
b5 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape = [num_labels]))

#w5 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden2, num_hidden3], stddev=0.1))
#b5 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape = [num_hidden3]))
variables = {
    'w1': w1, 'w2': w2, 'w3': w3, 'w4': w4, 'w5': w5, #'w6':w2_a,
    'b1': b1, 'b2': b2, 'b3': b3, 'b4': b4, 'b5': b5, #'b6':b2_a
}
return variables

def model_lenet5(data, variables):
    layer1_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(data, variables['w1'], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    layer1_actv = tf.sigmoid(layer1_conv + variables['b1'])
    layer1_pool = tf.nn.avg_pool(layer1_actv, [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

    layer2_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(layer1_pool, variables['w2'], [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME') #era Valid
    layer2_actv = tf.sigmoid(layer2_conv + variables['b2'])
    layer2_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(layer2_actv, [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

   # layer3_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(layer2_pool, variables['w6'], [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID') #era Valid
    #layer3_actv = tf.sigmoid(layer3_conv + variables['b6'])
    #layer3_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(layer3_actv, [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

    flat_layer = flatten_tf_array(layer2_pool)
    layer3_fccd = tf.matmul(flat_layer, variables['w3']) + variables['b3']
    layer3_actv = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer3_fccd)

    layer4_fccd = tf.matmul(layer3_actv, variables['w4']) + variables['b4']
    layer4_actv = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer4_fccd)
    #logits = tf.matmul(layer4_actv, variables['w5']) + variables['b5']
    logits = tf.matmul(layer4_actv, variables['w5']) + variables['b5']

    #layer5_fccd = tf.matmul(layer4_actv, variables['w5']) + variables['b5']
    #layer5_actv = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer5_fccd)
    #logits =tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(layer5_actv, variables['w6']) + variables['b6'])
    return logits
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. To find the feature representation of your image in the last fully connected layer, simply run that tensor in a TensorFlow session.

   ```
   with tf.Session() as sess:
       sess.run(layer4_actv, feed_dict={data: your_images_here})
   ```

   So that you have access to the tensors of your intermediate layers outside of your `model_lenet5()` function, you may want to store each Tensor in a dictionary and return that at the end.

   ```
   def model_lenet5(data, variables):
       model = {}
       model['layer1_conv'] = tf.nn.conv2d(data, variables['w1'], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
       model['layer1_actv'] = tf.sigmoid(layer1_conv + variables['b1'])
       # etc...
       return model

    model = model_lenet5(data, variables)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(model['layer4_actv'], feed_dict={data: your_images_here})
   ```

   Alternatively, you can use `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name()` to find the Tensor corresponding to the output of the last fully connected layer.

   ```
   layer4_actv = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer4_fccd, name='layer4_actv')

   with tf.Session() as sess:
       sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('layer4_actv:0'), feed_dict={data: your_images_here})
   ```
2. For a Tensor `x`, to get its shape as a list simply do `x.shape.as_list()`. You can the find the size of the input to your first fully connected layer by doing `flat_layer.shape.as_list()[0]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Problem 2 has been fixed. I wrote a shameful code, but it works, I'll clear up it later. As for issue 1 I'm trying to use your suggestions. I like the first proposal you gave me but I have some trouble in access 'layer4_actv' since it appears as 'not defined'.

Comment: I've edited my answer above to expand on how you can make your local variable `layer4_actv` accessible outside of your function.